# MultiFileField Doesn't Return Files, returns _str_

Tags: python, flask, file-upload, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to upload multiple images using WTForms in Flask using "MultiFileField, however, it returns a string instead of the file object.
So I tried using the below:

```
request.files.getlist(form.upload_field.data)
```

But it returns an empty list, so anyway I can handle this to save the photos to a directory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is documentation of file uploads with Flask [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/#uploading-files), and you are going about it the right way through accessing the `request.files` object. I've come across two ways to get an empty list back from there:

**1. `enctype` form html attribute not set**

Here's an example template that renders the `MultipleFileField()`:

```py
template = """
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{{ form.upload_field() }}
{{ form.submit() }}
</form>
"""
```

If I remove the `enctype=...` part, the list of files returns empty, where it otherwise would have values. A [page on the internet](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/att_form_enctype.asp) says:

> This value is required when you are using forms that have a file upload control

**2. Passing the wrong Key to `request.files.getlist()`**

`request.files` is a [`werkzeug.MultiDict`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.16.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict), which is a mapping of keys to values, designed to handle having multiple values for the same key.

Using the same form template as above, inspecting the keys of `request.files` (`print(list(request.files.keys()))`) upon POST reveals `['upload_field']`.

[`werkzeug.MultiDict.getlist`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.16.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.getlist) has a single *required* parameter:

> **key** - The key to be looked up.

So the only key in the MultiDict instance at this point is the string `'upload_field'`, if we want to get anything back from the `getlist` method, this needs to be the key that we pass to `getlist`. In your example code, you pass the value of the `form.upload_field.data` attribute (which in my tests is `None`). Change that to `'upload_field'` and you should be away.

Here's a working minimal example that will print the result of calling `request.files.getlist()` upon form submit. Run the script, visit `http://127.0.0.1:5000` in your browser, upload a couple of files and watch the terminal output.

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template_string, request
from wtforms import Form, MultipleFileField, SubmitField


app = Flask(__name__)


class MyForm(Form):
    upload_field = MultipleFileField()
    submit = SubmitField()


template = """
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{{ form.upload_field() }}
{{ form.submit() }}
</form>
"""


@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def route():
    form = MyForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.files.getlist("upload_field"))
    return render_template_string(template, form=form)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for that, I didn't realize the "Key" part which was the main reason returning None.